# Unable to set focus on Java applet via calling "requestFocus()" method from java script on MAC

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a java applet embedded in we page. When i "Click Me" link get focus it calls a method "focusApplet" in java script. This method is calling "requestFocus()" method of applet. Function "focusApplet" is being executed successfully. But focus is not moving inside the applet on all the browsers on MAC including safari 5,Firefox and chrome. But the same piece of code is working on windows platform. I tried "requestFocusInWindow()" method also but it was not working. Please help me to get rid of the problem.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sayhello(){
                var name = document.getElementById('hellotext');
                name.focus();
                name.click();
                name.value = "raman";
            }
            function focusMe() {
                alert('Hello world!!');
                document.getElementById('hellotext').focus();
            }
            function show() {
                var name = document.getElementById('name');
                var address = document.getElementById('address');
                alert("Hello " + name.value + " Your Address is : " + address.value);// + address.value
            }
            function focusApplet(){
                document.getElementsByName('mediamaster')[0].requestFocus();
            }
        </script>
        <form>
            Text : <input type="text" id="mytext" >
            Address : <input type="text" id="address" >
            <div >
                <a  id="medialink" href="#" onfocus="focusApplet();">Click Me</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <APPLET name="mediamaster" CODE="FirstApplet.class" WIDTH="200"
                        HEIGHT="200" name="FirstApplet" id="fA"></APPLET>
            </div>
            Name : <input type="text" id="hellotext"> Address : <input type="text">
            <input type="reset">
            <button value="Show" onclick="show()">show</button>
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The applet code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDocument;
import com.sun.java.browser.dom.DOMAccessor;
import com.sun.java.browser.dom.DOMAction;
import com.sun.java.browser.dom.DOMService;
import com.sun.java.browser.dom.DOMUnsupportedException;

public class FirstApplet extends Applet {
    private Button clear_button;
    private Choice color_choices;
    private Button button;
    public void init() {

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.green);
        try {
            service = DOMService.getService(this);
        } catch (DOMUnsupportedException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        final JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        // Create a button and add it to the applet.
        // Also, set the button's colors
        clear_button = new Button("Clear");
        clear_button.setForeground(Color.black);
        clear_button.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        button = new Button("Push Me");
        this.add(clear_button);
        this.add(button);
        // Create a menu of colors and add it to the applet.
        // Also set the menus's colors and add a label.
        color_choices = new Choice();
        color_choices.addItem("black");
        color_choices.addItem("red");
        color_choices.addItem("yellow");
        color_choices.addItem("green");
        color_choices.setForeground(Color.black);
        color_choices.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        this.add(new Label("Color: "));
        this.add(color_choices);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!!! Thread2");
                win.eval("sayhello()");
            }
        });

    }
}
```